# fusion-tables custom layout for card view

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Please help:

I'm trying to use a custom inline css display in the "custom layout" option on the card display of a table. 
When I save the custom css it shows it in the card display, but when I re-load the page, it reverts back to the standard display (just the first 10 columns with no formatting)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that we are working on now. It should be fixed soon. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: soon as in the next few days, or soon as in months to come?